# How do you allocate a space using malloc for an already defined array?

Tags: c++, dynamic

for example I have char buf[0]; and now I want to allocate more space to that array, making it 8 byte. This is part of an assignment, I'm not allowed to make a new array or dynamically allocate it in the first place.

Comment: Once an array has been sized, that size cannot be changed. If you are not allowed to work with dynamic allocations, you'll have to ask your instructor a few pointed questions such as "What the <expletive deleted>, dude?" But first I recommend a softer approach and re-reading the assignment specification. Odds are pretty good you've misinterpreted it.

Comment: `char buf[0];` is not allowed in standard C++ in the first place. Static array sizes must be at least 1.

Comment: "I have char buf[0];"  This code generates a warning.  Please consider enabling more warning features for your compiles.  For instance, my compiler settings report "warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array ‘buff’ [-Wpedantic]"  I suspect this is the answer your instructor wants from you ... the C++ language does not allow a 0 length array.

Comment: he did something for sure that actually allows char buf[0] and generates no warnings. Thanks everyone for trying to help. It's a big assignment. This is what he said " the zero-length array is just a shortcut for you to access the key. Without it, you'd need to do something like (char*)node + sizeof(SkipListNode) to access the key."

Answer (score 1):

**About memory allocation in C**

Memory for declared variables is allocated on the stack at compile time and **cannot** be changed at runtime.
To dynamically allocate memory at runtime, you use the. `malloc()` function with a pointer variable which is allocated on the heap. Any memory on the heap can only have a pointer variable that points to the memory and no regularly declared variables can refer to this memory.
Syntax:

```
type* ptr = (type*) malloc(sizeof(type)) * number_of_locations);
```

**Reallocating a dynamically allocated memory `malloc()` without losing old data**

You can use the `realloc()` function.

```
ptr = (type*) realloc(ptr, sizeof(type)) * new_number_of_locations);
```

Secondly,
`char buf[0]` should not compile and  even if it does has no effect  and writing to it may result in a segmentation fault.

Comment: Fun fact: You do not usually have to cast the return value of `malloc` in C. I say usually because I don't know of any, but I haven't done C in quite a while now. I may have forgotten some or new Standard revisions may have added a few.